# Transfer orientation of points to bone armature

Tags: python, scripting, quaternion

I am trying to transfer position of 2 points into a bone, so that the bone has the same direction as the 2 points
I tried it with this initial position
[image]
this is the output after running the code
[image]

this is the code

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector, Quaternion
use_bone = bpy.data.objects['Armature'].pose.bones['Bone']
 
p1 = bpy.data.objects['Point.001'].location
p2 = bpy.data.objects['Point.002'].location

 
p_v = p2-p1
 
loc_h = Vector(use_bone.head)
loc_t = Vector(use_bone.tail)
loc_v = loc_t - loc_h
 
q = loc_v.rotation_difference(p_v)

use_bone.rotation_quaternion = use_bone.rotation_quaternion @ q
```

It doesnt even close to what I was expecting, anyone please help

Edit:
I tried XY comments, if the bone has random head and tail, the script doesnt work.... this is the example : initial
[image]
After run the code
[image]

I appreciate the help, just a little bit more help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Get the scene to test

[image]

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

def add_empty(loc):
    bpy.ops.object.empty_add(location=loc)

def get_scene_to_test(): # clear scene and add bone
    objects = bpy.data.objects
    for obj in objects:
        objects.remove(obj)

    bpy.ops.object.armature_add(enter_editmode=True, align='WORLD', location=(1,1,1), rotation=(1,1,1))
    ob = bpy.context.object
    bone = ob.data.edit_bones[0]
    bone.head = 1,1,1
    bone.tail = 2,3,4
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    b = ob.data.bones[0]
    p0 = ob.matrix_world @ b.head_local
    p1 = ob.matrix_world @ b.tail_local
    add_empty(p0)
    add_empty(p1)

# make sure in object mode and have a active object
get_scene_to_test()
```

#### Change the head and tail position in a specific direction in world space

[image]

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

def add_empty(loc):
    bpy.ops.object.empty_add(location=loc)

new_head_loc = Vector((3,3,3))
new_tail_loc = Vector((5,5,5))

add_empty(new_head_loc)
add_empty(new_tail_loc)

ob = bpy.data.objects["Armature"]
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = ob
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bone = ob.data.edit_bones[0]
mat = ob.matrix_world.inverted()
bone.head = mat @ new_head_loc
bone.tail = mat @ new_tail_loc
```

Comment: Great answer, can you give me an example if the head and/or tail not at the 0,0,0. it still confuses me. thanks for the help

Comment: I tested it can work if the head and/or tail not at the 0,0,0. Is your object has non-zero rotation or parent?

Comment: and make sure you are running in object mode.

Comment: `>>> print(p1)
<Vector (1.5247, -0.0280, 0.6231)>

>>> print(p2)
<Vector (0.5795, 0.9002, 1.6301)>

>>> print(bone.head)
<Vector (0.1049, 2.2131, -0.9436)>

>>> print(bone.tail)
<Vector (0.8820, -0.0379, 1.5107)>`

This is the REST position of my bone... and location of my point
after running your script I get  this :
`>>> print(p1)
<Vector (1.5247, -0.0280, 0.6231)>

>>> print(p2)
<Vector (0.5795, 0.9002, 1.6301)>

>>> print(bone.head)
<Vector (0.1049, 2.2131, -0.9436)>

>>> print(bone.tail)
<Vector (2.9421, 2.1281, 0.9637)>`

it is not close to point vector.

Comment: Try the new one and see if it's the same as me.

Comment: yes I got the same, but if I manually add the bone, and run your code, I cannot get the same result.... try add the bone manually, and run your code, do you get the expected result? I think the reason is that when you created the bone, by default it is erect perfectly at z axis, if you manually modify the z axis so that the bone is not perfectly erect, you will not get the result you are expected

Comment: I noticed this problem because edit-bones and pose-bones have different data. I will update the answer later.

Comment: You are an angle.... WOW, I will waiting for your answer, it has been 2 weeks I was working on this problem

Comment: `use_bone.rotation_quaternion` in your script is pose rotation, not edit mode rotation, so there have 3 transform: object transform, bone transform, bone pose transform. And `Y`, `Z` in pose transform are flipped.

Comment: CMIIW, I want to edit the pose and add keyframe later, that is why I am using pose rotation instead of edit mode rotation. your script if fine but if the initial bone is NOT fully erect, I cannot get the right transformation towards the same vector as the 2 points

Comment: This one should success for any head and tail, but not sure is it true when have bone parent and non-zero pose location.