# Pointing bone at the middle of 2 points using plane

Tags: python, scripting, bones, motion-capture

I am trying to create a bone that rotates in the way a wrist would rotate when the hand is moved. I have locations of specific points on the hand, the wirst, the start of the pinky finger and the start of the index finger. If I were to create a point inbetween those two and use the Track To constraint, this one point will not accurately represent the rotations of the wrist. Which is why I create my own rotation matrix.

The y axis of the bone needs to point at the middle of the index finger and the pinky finger. While the z axis of the bone would be in the same direction as the normal of the plane that can be created between the 3 points.

This is what I have so far.

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix
from mathutils import Vector
def planeRotation(origin, point1, point2):

    # Point in middle of 2 points
    mid = (Vector(point1) + Vector(point2)) / 2
    y_vec = mid - Vector(origin)
    y_n = y_vec.normalized()

    vector_left = Vector(point2) - Vector(origin)
    vector_right = Vector(point1) - Vector(origin)
    z_vec = vector_left.cross(vector_right)
    z_n = z_vec.normalized()

    x_n = z_n.cross(y_n)


    M = Matrix([
        [x_n[0], x_n[1], x_n[2], 0.0],
        [y_n[0], y_n[1], y_n[2], 0.0],
        [z_n[0], z_n[1], z_n[2], 0.0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1.0]
    ])

    return M


bpy.data.objects["Armature"].pose.bones["Bone"].matrix = planeRotation(point1, point2, point3)
```

Where point1 is the location of the bone head, point2 is the location of the pinky finger and point3 is the location of the index finger. But this does not seem to properly rotate the bone. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: maybe able to help:  
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/265213/transfer-orientation-of-points-to-bone-armature/265241#265241