# How to stretch armature according to two different points

Tags: python, scripting

I an trying to create my own addon. I have a button which adds two points for positioning ("Start_point" and "End_point"). Then another button should stretch a bone between the two points. I was trying to first add an armature at one point and then stretch it toward another. Here is my code for the first part:

```
  import bpy

  get_object_1 = bpy.data.objects["Start_point"]
  
  bpy.ops.object.armature_add(enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=location1, scale=(1, 1, 1))
```

About how to stretch the bone, I have no idea. I tried doing it manually, copying the code from the "Info" in scripting tab and then editing the location of the stretch by another variable, but it did not work. So how can I achieve this.

I know that this is not that difficult, and I am sorry for posting this. But please bear with me, I am quite new to scripting in Blender.

Comment: This might help if you want to edit bone/pose bone head/tail positions: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/265213/transfer-orientation-of-points-to-bone-armature/265241#265241

Comment: That might be of some help, I will try it and get back to you, **@XY**

Comment: Not what I am looking for .. Sorry **@XY**