# blender python transfer pose bone position to an object (matrix issue)

Tags: python, armature, bones, matrix

I have an object inside a bone, matches the bone exactly (position, scale, rotation). The armature and the object have different origin points.

I am trying to make the object follow the bone exactly when i change its position - rotation using python.

I am guessing my math is wrong (works if the object has 0,0,0 as original position )

[image]

And here is the code and the file so it will be easier to prototype

[image]

```
from mathutils import Matrix
import bpy



ob = bpy.context.active_pose_bone
obj = ob.id_data

T =  Matrix.Translation(1* (ob.tail - ob.head))
matrix_final = obj.matrix_world @ (T@ ob.matrix_channel)

obj2 = bpy.data.objects["Bone.001|Armature"]
obj2.matrix_world = matrix_final
```

Thanks

Comment: This post may help you find a solution: 
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/265213/transfer-orientation-of-points-to-bone-armature

Answer (score 0):

Couple of possible issues;

1. It looks like you've rigged this in an odd way... basically bones need to be aligned to meshes in EDIT MODE not 'posed' into position in POSE MODE, if that's done there's a coordinate mismatch between the two if the bone is reset.
2. Ideally you want to make sure both objects ORIGIN's are in the same location with Rotation, Location & Scale fixed - coordinates are all relative.
3. Instead of `(1* (ob.tail - ob.head))` try `(0* (ob.tail - ob.head))`; using "1" is offsetting the mesh along the bones Z axis so it roots to the tail bone node.